# go api webserver: total post request json data not taking as input

Tags: api, go, webserver

i made a api server to store the details of students. here the json keys are

- StudentName
- RollNo
- Gender
- Branch
  when i send these values in post request , only **Gender** and **branch** values are storing.

**code:**

```
func PostStudentDetails(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        var student studentDb

        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&student)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }

        student.CreatedOn = time.Now()
        id = id + 1
        k := strconv.Itoa(id)
        studentData[k] = student

        j, err := json.Marshal(student)
        if err != nil {
                panic(err)
        }
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
        w.Write(j)
        log.Printf("%s", j)
        log.Printf("%s", studentData)

}
```

**i sent this json data in post request:**

```
{
    "StudentName": "test name",
    "RollNo": "test number",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Branch": "test "
}
```

but StudentName and RollNo are not stored

**Response:**

```
{"name":"","roll no":"","branch":"test ","gender":"Male","createdon":"2022-06-25T10:11:22.340365545Z"}
```

**response log:**
see this image [log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWvFu.png)

Comment: `"StudentName"` != `"name"`, and `"RollNo"` != `"roll no"`. If your struct's `StudentName` field has a tag `json:"name"` then you can unmarshal only `"name"` into it, the `"StudentName"` in the incoming JSON will simply be ignored. Same goes for `RollNo string \`json:"roll no"\``.

Comment: yes my structs `StudentName` field has `json:"name"` , then how can i unmarshal only `"name"`?? i changed the `"name"` to `"studentname"` then it working. but i didn't get it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the json data you are sending to your app, can you please make sure that your Student struct has json tags that match the json payload.

So if you are sending in this json data

```
{
    "StudentName": "test name",
    "RollNo": "test number",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "Branch": "test "
}
```

Then your `Student` struct should have the json tags match the json field names. Notice how the part in backticks on each field is the same as the expected field name on the incoming payload.

```
type Student struct {
    StudentName string `json:"StudentName,omitempty"`
    RollNo      string `json:"RollNo,omitempty"`
    Gender      string `json:"Gender,omitempty"`
    Branch      string `json:"Branch,omitempty"`
}
```